# How to handle 'Next' button programmatically in SurveyJS? (survey-react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, surveyjs

I have a survey page that created with SurveyJS lib(survey-react) and I have 2 problems:

1. I want to query back-end server when I click 'Next' button in the survey , if server return a true , then jump to next page , if false , stay in current page and do something else.

so what I need are:

1.to handle the event of 'Next' button myself.
2.to trigger next or previous event manually.

and the second problems is, if I have 2 input element in survey , and I want to show validation message if the amount of these two input more than 100.

is there a way to do these 2 requirements?
[image: img]

update:
now I override the 'Next' button event by getElementsByClassName , it can excute my function, but still trigger 'nextPage()'. is there a way to prevent the default event?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide built-in navigation and create your own. It about 10-20 lines of code.
Here is the live sample - https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library?id=navigation-custom&platform=Reactjs&theme=modern

Comment: And here is stand alone plunker sample - https://plnkr.co/edit/oQyzZu1cu6VLiymC